# FT_Get_Kerning returns 0 vector

Tags: character, freetype, kerning

I check if my TTF file has kerning information using  FT_HAS_KERNING, and this returns true.

I then use:

```
 FT_Vector delta;
 FT_Get_Kerning( face, prev, next, FT_KERNING_DEFAULT, &delta );
```

to determine the kerning value, but both delta.x and delta.y have values of 0.

From the docs it seems that this means an error has occurred - how can I debug what the problem is even though FT_HAS_KERNING returns true?

All I want to do is fix the spacing between characters, as they currently appear strangely spaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up downloading the TTX tool to look inside my TTF file and it turns out there was no kerning information in here for the pairs I desired.

Answer (score -1):

With parameter `FT_KERNING_DEFAULT` it always returns `0`.
See [FT Kerning Mode](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Kerning_Mode).

Use `FT_KERNING_UNFITTED` instead.